# Regex Negative Lookahead in Web Page

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to come up with a regex that will match all code in a web page unless it contains a certain phrase.

I'm testing it on this string:

```
<html> This is a web page </html>
```

It should look at the entire string before the word 'is', see that 'is' is present, and return a non-match. The negative lookahead portion of this will be much more specific in my implementation, I just wanted to give a simple example.

The regex I'm trying to use looks like this:

```
^[\s\S]+(?!is)[\s\S]+$
```

This consists of the beginning of the string:

```
(^)
```

literally anything:

```
([\s\S]+)
```

negative lookahead:

```
((?!is))
```

another literally anything:

```
([\s\S]+)
```

and end of string:

```
($)
```

I'm using a scanning tool that takes a selenium authentication script. When the tool runs the script, it uses a regex to find a value on the web page after authentication to verify that the login script ran correctly. This regex value is different for every single site I scan. But all of the sites it's visiting use the same authentication method that will always show the same page if authentication fails. So basically I need to come up with a regex that will fail if this bad login page is displayed, I'm currently trying to employ a negative lookahead to accomplish this. The scanner is kind of dumb, so the regex is the only way I can interact with this authentication verification process.

Comment: `(?!is)` is at a position between characters. All the total regex has to do is find any position where there is not an `is` ahead. That looks to be (where comma's are) `<,h,t,m,l,>, ,T,hi,s, I,s, ,a, ,w,e,b, ,p,a,g,e, ,<,/,h,t,m,l>`

Comment: What you can do is use a look ahead once, at the beginning for the `is`. If it is found, it won't match by using a negative lookahead:. `^(?![\S\s]*is)[\S\s]+$` Note- that inside assertions they all are _compelled_ to match. Then, it just looks at the negative or positive to return a true or false.

Comment: Thanks, @sln! Your answer got me part of the way there in that it won't match anything up to the point where the negative lookahead occurs. However, it does continue to match everything following the text in the negative lookahead. I'm currently trying to find a way to also incorporate a lookbehind to correct this, but any advice you can add would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The theory is the same https://regex101.com/r/GiWqb0/1 This uses word boundary's around the `is` and uses the dot in this example regex `^(?!.*\bis\b).*$` and multi-line mode for a test. It's my understanding you don't want to match _anything_ in the string if `is` is there, correct ?

Comment: Hi @sln, yes, you're correct. I didn't realize it at the time I posted the question, but I believe the regex is being applied to the entire page in multiline mode. For example, in the link you provided, I would want to return 0 matches based on all of the text in the test string field, not just the line it occurs on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem and wanted to share it here in case anyone ever stumbles across this thread. I ended up using a negative lookbehind to achieve the targeted functionality. Since the regex is being executed in multiline mode, I had to make my match string look at the very last bit of text on the page. Then the lookbehind would search everything that came before the match string. Since this was happening at the very end of the page, the engine couldn't advance any further and the result from the last line was retained.

Answer (score 0):

The first alternative matches non-whitespace characters, while the second alternative matches any whitespace not followed by 'is' plus a whitespace.

```
^(\S|\s(?!is\s))*$
```

Taken together, as above, they should achieve the desired result

Comment: This does accomplish what I'm looking for for for individual lines, but I think the scanner I'm using is searching in multiline mode, and so I still get a match on some lines that 'is' doesn't occur in.